# Trace of the action of the Hecke algebra

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory

Let $G$ be any finite group, $H$ a subgroup of $G$, and $\mathcal{R}$ the Hecke algebra associated to this data (i.e. the space of $H$-bi-invariant maps $G \longrightarrow \mathbb{C}$ with the multiplicative stucture given by the convolution product).

Now let $(V,\pi)$ be an irreducible complex representation of $G$. Then $V^H$ has a natural $\mathcal{R}$-module structure given by
$$ \phi . v = \frac{1}{|G|} \sum_{g \in G} \phi(g) \pi(g) v $$
I have often been told that the $\mathcal{R}$-module $V^H$ more or less determines $\pi$, but I've never found an answer to the following question : how can one calculate the character of $\pi$ only from the data of the endomorphism $v \mapsto \phi.v$ ? Is it enough to know the trace of $v \mapsto \phi.v$ ?

Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 0):

The choice $\phi$ being the Dirac delta at $1$ gives you the trace.